# What is the difference between a page and thread?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory, process-scheduling, paging, threads

"Each process that is executed is divided into blocks of same size, called pages."
"Thread is a part of process being executed."

Are pages and threads both part(s) of process? Whats the difference between **thread as a part of process** and **page as a part of process**?

Comment: Pages are blocks of *memory*.

Comment: That's like asking what's the difference between a steering wheel and a cup holder, which are both part of a car. You need to learn what a "page" is, and what a "thread" is. They are not things that can be reasonably compared.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at very vague descriptions and asking "What's the difference between these things that haven't been described properly?" For a more detailed understanding, you should, well, look for more detail, which is widely available.

A page is a block of memory; a thread is a sequence of instructions to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Paging is something to deal with memory management and Thread is an instance of a program . When we execute a multithreaded program it may have to refer memory addresses , so a thread might use a page table to access the main memory address.